# Office JS Excel - How to get the cell name instead of the value?

Tags: office-js

I'm developing an Office Add-in for Excel with the Office JS library.  I am binding to cells in the sheet and retrieving their values via getDataAsync().  However, it seems I am only able to get the actual value in the cell.  But what I want is to be able to list what cell it is as well, such as 'A1'.  How do I go about getting the cell name?

**Update:**

It does not look like there is a range property accessible in a Binding object when creating one via addFromPromptAsync().  So, an alternative would be to prompt the user for the range of cells and then create the binding after the user gives the range as a callback, instead of immediately.  Is there a different prompt method other than addFromPromptAsync() that will allow me to prompt the user for a range without creating a binding?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the getCell(row: number, column: number) method at the following link. The code snippet shows you how to use the address property to get the cell reference.

[Worksheet](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/worksheet)

Comment: The getCell() method requires a row and column.  However, those are not available to me from my binding.

Comment: I have a binding of type Office.BindingType.Text after calling addFromPromptAsync()

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently with the addFromPromptAsync method:
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/bind-to-regions-in-a-document-or-spreadsheet

Comment: For folks stumbling into this thread later:  see the complete answer re. `addFromPromptAsync` here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425179/678505

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things: If you have a binding, you should be able to get the associated range object and it's properties such as address using the getRange() method. See [here](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/binding) for details. Note that binding object also provides the `type` property to help identify if it is bound to range, table, etc.

Secondly, you should look at using the newer version of APIs such as [bindings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/bindingcollection) API to add the binding. It offers more richer and easier syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  However, the reason I didn't want to use the newer apis for creating the binding is specifically because I want to use the built-in prompt that addFromPromptAsync() provides.  The newer API doesn't provide a bind from prompt method.