# How to launch the Select Data dialog in Excel from a JS add-in

Tags: excel, office-js

How do I launch the "Select Data" dialog in Excel from a JavaScript add-in so the user can select a cell for the add-in to add data?

Comment: If the user is just going to select a cell, they just need to click it. There's no dialog for that. Can you add some detail to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to do this using the `addFromPromptAsync` method. There is a great writeup on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44425179/11453853

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to range selector dialog (similar to the one used in data validation within Excel), it is not supported. The options are to listen in on selection changed event and get the range address from selection.